# How do I order a dictionary based off of another dictionary? C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

So what I am trying to do is order a dictionary(dict2) based off of another dictionary's(dict1) ordering based off of its Key; The two dictionaries have the same Values but not the same keys. 
There is a graph below to visualize what I am trying to do.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1BRS.png)

Comment: Dictionaries are key based. The order of keys is not a thing for those. Indeed the lack of order matering is a reason they (unlike lists, arrays and other index based stuff) **can** be made threadsave. You could maybe have them sorted in some way during output, but how to go about that tends to be based on your UI technology moer then actuall code.

Comment: Please explain what you are doing it **for**, this would help the community come up with the best answers.

Comment: What you could certainly do is: Make a class, struct or tupel that holds both parts of the key/value pair. Make a array of that type. Sort said array or build it fully sorted by your rules.

Comment: @tymtam I'm doing this for ordering, since I have not coded in C# for a while instead I have been coding in Java and I'm trying to figure out something similar to the HashMap in Java.

Comment: @Rufus L Just noticed the my error in the picture its supposed to be dict2 instead of dict1, ill change that right away.

Comment: @RodneyJoll The ordering is means to some goal. I was asking about the goal, i.e. Why do you want them ordered?

Comment: @tymtam So I can receive a value from a database.

Comment: Why is the order important for retrieving from the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Linq to order one dictionary by the index of it's value in the other dictionary. There is probably a shorter way to do it, but this should work:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {12, "hello"},
    {67, "green"},
    {29, "blue"},
    {15, "red"},
    {40, "house"}
};

var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"tree", "green"},
    {"person", "hello"},
    {"car", "red"},
    {"floor", "red"},
    {"dirt", "green"},
};

var ordered = dict2
    .OrderBy(d2Item => dict1.FirstOrDefault(d1Item => d1Item.Value == d2Item.Value).Key)
    .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for.